# how to add hide event to the button in webform?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net

im trying to hide div by clicking the button, but it does hide it for a second and return the div (looks like it refreshing page).here is my html code :

```
<div id="page">
<p>First Paragraph</p>
<p>Second Paragraph</p>
<p>Yet one more Paragraph</p>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
</div>
```

and here is my jquery code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Button1").click(function () {
            $("#page").hide();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What Rick said in his answer AND you need to add `Type="Button"` to your button.

```
<Button ID="Button1" type="button">Button</button>
```

The default button type is submit, which will cause the page refresh. AND, as Rick mentioned, ASP buttons will also submit.  So, you need to use an HTML button and set the `type="button"` attribute.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button)

> The type of the button. Possible values are:
>
> submit: The button submits the form data to the server. **This is the default if the attribute is not specifie**d, or if the attribute
>   is dynamically changed to an empty or invalid value.
>
> reset: The button resets all the controls to their initial values.
>
> button: The button has no default behavior. It can have client-side scripts associated with the element's events, which are
>   triggered when the events occur.

Answer (score 0):

An ASP Button with runat="server" causes a server post-back. If you aren't going to be acting on that click from the server, just use a client-side button like:

```
<button id="Button1" type="button">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the client id mode to static on the button, then it'll work. It's not working because that hasn't been specified so the name is changing.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" ClientIDMode ="Static" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

If you wanted to disable the postback to simply hide something without processing anything, then just using a client side button is the best option.